# Multiple classes present in one-hot encoding

Tags: neural-network, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, one-hot-encoding

When dealing with classification for multiple classes present in the same sample, can the output layer have the form of one-hot encoding, but instead of only one hot, have multiple?
That is, in case of a only single class being present in the sample, the encoding could be [0,1,0]. For multiple classes in the same sample, can it be [0,1,1]? And if yes, what loss function should be used?

Comment: I am a bit confused. When you say *input*, du you mean sample? To my understanding, you are asking about samples that can belong to multiple multiple classes? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, by input I mean sample. And also yes, the same sample belongs to more than one class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it exactly as you describe it. This is called **multilabel-classification**.

If doing so, you would treat each element of the output as an independent prediction of a binary classification problem, i.e. the first element would predict, if the sample belongs to class 1, the second element would predict if the sample belongs to class 2 and so on.

As a loss function, you could take the sum of the cross-entropy loss per output element. If you have $m$ classes, $y=(y_1,\ldots, y_m)$ would be the binary target and $\hat{y}=(\hat{y}_1,\ldots,\hat{y}_m)$ would be your prediction, then the loss could be
$$\mathcal{L}=\sum_{j=1}^m -y_j\log \hat{y}_j - (1-y_j)\log (1-\hat{y}_j)$$